# How to create HttpServletRequest object in struts2 action

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am trying to set some values in HttpServletRequest object in struts2 action but on JSP page, it is showing it as null.

Code on struts.xml is:

```
<action name="login" method="execute" class="com.ui.LoginAction">
    <result name="success">/tc/login.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/tc/session_timeout.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

Action class is:

```
package com.ui;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;


public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware{

private String username;
private String password;

HttpServletRequest request;

public String execute() {
    try
    {

        request.setAttribute("demo", "value Stored in Request....");

        return "success"; 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(Constants.LOG_NAME).error("Error with action!",e);
        return "error";
    }
}

public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.request = request;
}

public HttpServletRequest getServletRequest() {
    return this.request;
}


public String getJ_password()
{
   return this.password;
}

public String getJ_username()
{
   return this.username;
}

public void setJ_password(String string)
{
   this.password = string;
}

public void setJ_username(String string)
{
   this.username = string;
}

}
```

Code on JSP Page is:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome Page - Struts 2 - Login Application</title>
</head>

<body>
    Login Page...<br>
    <%= request.getAttribute("demo") %>
</body>
</html>
```

But on JSP Page it is showing as null.

Any idea on this?

Comment: My requirement is to set values in HttpServletRequest object in one namespace and access it in another namespace. But I am not able to access it. From the above code, I should get values on JSP page but still it is showing it as null.

Comment: Don't use scriplets. With S2 you don't need to put values into a request.

Comment: @Aleksandr From above code, does it means that HttpServletRequest object is not created properly as I am not able to retrieves value stored in request?

Comment: Why do you want to spend time finding why it isn't working if that is not preferred way to do this in S2 app. Take a look at posted answer.

Comment: The point is that you don't *need* to do it like this. That aside, if you're saying this doesn't work, then something else is wrong.

Comment: @Rahul It's not created if the method is not called.

Comment: @RomanC from the initial JSP page I am submitting a form through which "login" action is getting called. So any how execute method of LoginAction will get called.

Comment: @AleksandrM : My application requirement is to set values in HttpServletRequest object in action of first namespace and access it in action of second namespace. I am using the concept of Action Chaining. But in the action of second namespace the request values are null. So from above code, I was trying to figure out whether these request values are present in same namespace or not, but still it shows it as null.

Comment: @Rahul In the initial JSP page you don't have such attribute, if the action is called then you will see it in the JSP page.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an attribute as a class variable in your action class and put a getter for it. In your jsp you can then access it using struts tags.

java code

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware{
  private String demo;

  public String getDemo(){return this.demo;}

  public String execute() {
    try
    {
        //request.setAttribute("demo", "value Stored in Request....");
        this.demo = "value stored in request";
        return "success"; 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(Constants.LOG_NAME).error("Error with action!",e);
        return "error";
    }
  }
}
```

JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<s:property value="demo" />
```